# Open connections on AWS host?

Tags: amazon-web-services, database-connection, amazon-ec2

On my EC2 instance, I never closed database connections, which was my mistake.

1. Will shutting down and restarting my application release resources ?
2. Will my open connections on AWS instance affect other customers on the same host ? If yes, what does amazon do to protect such breaches ?

Answer (score 0):

Which database is your application connecting to, is it on RDS? Those connections will not be released if you restart your application.

Restarting the database, on the other hand, will certainly release the resources.

Yes, the open connections to the database will affect others using the database. but those ideally should be other applications of yours. Amazon has nothing to do with this. They cannot tell if the way you use your connections is right or wrong. They will, however, alert you if your RDS instance is running out of connections.